# Ampersand.js — collection validation

Tags: javascript, ampersand.js

I use Ampersand.js for my app and I need to implement a Cart model, which contains two collections: 'products' and 'extras'.

The difference between the collections is that 'products' collection should store up to 5 items in it, while 'extras' one can contain as many as customer wants.

I feel that such validation should be placed in the collection itself, but how do I do that? It should also deal with multiple 'add' calls (e.g. `this.model.products.add([1,2,3])`).

I'd also appreciate any related links to docs, because I could not find any.

UPDATE: I can override 'add' method of collection in following way:

```
export const ProductCollection = Collection.extend({
  model: Product,

  // by default the collection is unlimited
  limit: Infinity,

  // custom `add` method doesnt allow to add
  // more than limit
  add(input, options) {
    // handle array or single item
    const items = Array.isArray(input) ? input : [input];

    // as many items as allowed by limit
    const sliced = items.slice(0, this.limit - this.length);
    this.constructor.__super__.add.call(this, sliced, options);
  },
});
```

The problem is that `Collection#set` method is still available for direct call. And this beast is much more difficult to patch (check out [source](https://github.com/AmpersandJS/ampersand-collection/blob/master/ampersand-collection.js#L56)). So I hope there's a better solution.

Comment: I'm not sure that the collection is the best place for this. So what should happen if you add 6 products with `set`? Should the error be thrown or only part of the products added?

Comment: Given that there is no built in functionality, you might be better off working with events. When you want to set or add products, trigger an event on your collection. And then in your event handler do whatever you need. And you can trigger another event if there is an error or something. This way you would also be safe using async checks.

Comment: Ok, I see. It seems that it really not such a good idea implement the validation via collections; or at least use events as you said.
Thank you for help, @amberv

Comment: you are welcome, good luck!